# jQuery Replacewith ( replace 2 elements )

Tags: jquery, replace

why dont this code replace both object and embed?

```
$(".watch-on-mobile").click(function () {
$('object' && 'embed').replaceWith($('.video-js'));
$('.video-js').css("display", "block")
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why did you think that would work...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't invent a syntax and hope for the library to guess.

Use [the multiple selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) :

```
$('object,embed').replaceWith($('.video-js'));
```